# How to use the YML structure of routes to control access to Group Content

Tags: 8, group

I am using the Group module and would like to leverage each Group's permissions in my module's yml files.

I have a `module.permissions.yml` with something like

```
tam_api.group_gid_members_uid:
  path: 'group/{group}/members/{member}'
  defaults: { _controller: '\Drupal\tam_api\Controller\TamApi::getGroupMember' }
  methods: [GET, HEAD]
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access user profiles'
  options:
    _format : ['json']
    _auth: ['oauth2', 'cookie']
    parameters:
      group:
        type: entity:group
      member:
        type: entity:group_content
```

I would like to change `access user profiles` to the `View individual group members` for the given Group?

Can this be done within the [Structure of Routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `group.services.yml` you'll find access_check entries like:

```
  access_check.group.permission:
    class: 'Drupal\group\Access\GroupPermissionAccessCheck'
    tags:
      - { name: 'access_check', applies_to: '_group_permission' }
  access_check.group.member:
    class: 'Drupal\group\Access\GroupMemberAccessCheck'
    tags:
      - { name: 'access_check', applies_to: '_group_member' }
```

you can use these in your routes like:

```
tam_api.group_gid_members_uid:
  path: 'group/{group}/members/{member}'
  defaults: { _controller: '\Drupal\tam_api\Controller\TamApi::getGroupMember' }
  methods: [GET, HEAD]
  requirements:
    _group_member: 'TRUE'
# or    _group_permission: 'view group membership content'
  options:
    _format : ['json']
    _auth: ['oauth2']
    parameters:
      group:
        type: entity:group
      member:
        type: entity:group_content
```

Note: the parameter argument must be named `{group}`